# Where is my viminfo file on Windows?

Tags: gvim, persistent-state, microsoft-windows

I have gVim 7.4.608 installed on Windows 7 at work.

I've looked in `C:\` , `C:\Users\<username>\AppData` , `C:\Program Files\vim` , `C:\Temp` but there's no sign of it. It must exist somewhere, command history is working OK. I just want to read the file, I don't care where it actually is.

From `:help viminfo`

```
The default name of the viminfo file is "$HOME/.viminfo" for Unix and OS/2,
"s:.viminfo" for Amiga, "$HOME\_viminfo" for MS-DOS and Win32.  For the last
two, when $HOME is not set, "$VIM\_viminfo" is used.  When $VIM is also not
set, "c:\_viminfo" is used.  For OS/2 "$VIM/.viminfo" is used when $HOME is
not set and $VIM is set.
```

The variables `%HOME%` and `%VIM%` were not set in my Windows environment.

I couldn't look in directory `C:\Users\<username>\Application Data`.

Comment: Why are you looking for that file?

Comment: Wanted to grab some stuff out of the command history

Comment: @ropata `q:` is very helpful for this, it gives you a Vim buffer allowing you to search, edit, etc your command history.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Windows, the home directory is set in `%USERPROFILE%`. I believe vim will use this as `$HOME`.

In my case, the `_viminfo` is located in the `C:\Users\<username>`, which is the home directory, while the `%HOME%` is not set as well.

Comment: It was indeed in `C:\Users\<username>\_viminfo`. The command `:echo $HOME` works a charm as well.

Comment: @ropata The command `echo $HOME` only works in the PowerShell, not in the cmd. But maybe no one is using cmd anymore? :D

Comment: thanks for the Powershell tip, I called `echo $HOME` from the vim command line with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the `HOME` variable isn't set? I have encountered cases where `ENV` was not set, but `HOME` always seems to be assigned a value in my (G)Vim instances.

If you type `echo $HOME` in command mode, Vim should display what value is set for `HOME`. Alternatively, you can try `e $HOME\.viminfo` and see if this opens the contents of the .viminfo file. If this is the case, you have found it!

Comment: Except it will be `_viminfo`, not `.viminfo`, in WIndows.

Comment: This answer clarifies why I can't find or $HOME or %HOME% in Windows.. it's a Vim-only variable! So it is accessible from vim command line.

Answer (score 1):

For corporative environments usually is set the `%HOMEDRIVE` and `%HOMEPATH%` and the GVIM use it (version 8.1 at least) .

option.txt help file :

```
                            *$HOME-windows*
On MS-Windows, if $HOME is not defined as an environment variable, then
at runtime Vim will set it to the expansion of $HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH.
If $HOMEDRIVE is not set then $USERPROFILE is used.

This expanded value is not exported to the environment, this matters when
running an external command: >
    :echo system('set | findstr ^HOME=')
and >
    :echo luaeval('os.getenv("HOME")')
should echo nothing (an empty string) despite exists('$HOME') being true.
When setting $HOME to a non-empty string it will be exported to the
subprocesses.
```